# I need help on what to do next JS

Tags: javascript, forms, css, radio-button

```
             <form>
               <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male </br>
               <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
             </form>
```

example: when I check male and then I will go navigation and choose clothing so it will sort out the things that will be shown in clothing are all male clothing vice versa

[sample html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMHd.png)

[sample navigation after choosing male or female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDJNc.png)

Comment: The thing to do next is to work through some JavaScript and web books and/or tutorials. (Seriously, this is not sarcasm.) Stack Overflow is for *specific*, targeted questions. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What about if a user is neither male or female?

Comment: I get your point that's why I registered in stack as a student why stackoverflow allowed..NO SARCASM

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9l349m6r5s9yaj/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: if they check male it will show male apparelif female it will show female apparel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <form>
          <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender"value="Male">Male
          <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
        </form>

        <li>
        <a id="accesory" href="accesroy">Accesory</a>
          <a id="maleapparel" style="display:none" href="maleapparellink">Male Apparel</a>
          <a id="femaleapparel" style="display:none" href="femaleapparellink">Female Apparel</a>
        </li>

    <---js--->
    <script>
$(document).on('click','#male',function(){
    $("#accesory").hide();
        $("#femaleapparel").hide();
        $("#maleapparel").show();
    });
    $(document).on('click','#female',function(){
            $("#accesory").hide();
        $("#maleapparel").hide();
        $("#femaleapparel").show();
    });
</script>
    <---js--->
```

Comment: your a life saver dude

Comment: I have one tiny little question.  Do I need to create 2 sets of the main page 1 set for male and 1 set for female. am I correct

Comment: yeah! that will be the easy step for you.

Comment: example: when I check male and then I will go navigation and choose clothing so it will sort out the things that will be shown in clothing are all male clothing vice versa